# Proof of polynomial division

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Consider $K$ a field,let $f(x),g(x) \in K[x]$ and $a \in K$. Proof that if $x-a | f(x)$ and $x-a$ not divide $g(x)$ then $x-a$ not divide $h(x) = f(x)+g(x)$.

I’m trying to do it by contradiction then:

I suppose that $x-a$ divide $h(x) = f(x)+g(x)$  then by the definition of divisibility in polynomials we know that $b(x)$ divide $a(x)$ if and only if  $q(x) \in K[x]$ such that $a(x) =b(x) q(x)$.

Then we have that:

$f(x) = (x-a)$ $q(x)$

And that’s what I have for now, Am I doing all right? or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Induction is the wrong approach.  Think instead of a simple example from integers as inspiration.  If $3$ divides $9$, but does not divide $8$, then $3$ doesn't divide $9 + 8 = 17$.  Work from there.

Comment: What you have is $h(x)=(x-a)q(x)$, not $f(x)=(x-a)q(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is as follow : suppose $x-a|f(x)$ and $x-a|f(x)+g(x)$, then $x-a|(g(x)+f(x))-f(x)=g(x)$ which is a contradiction.